# Implementing your own Membership Provider in ASP.NET MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, membership-provider

Are there are any specific rules and regulation to follow while developing a custom membership provider. Like, implementing a particular Interface or Abstract class. Or a definite model architecture to follow.

If yes, then what are the rules or I am free to design, model and code anything ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First rule is don't reinvent the wheel -- the built-in SQL membership provider is quite good, especially at pure membership stuff. If you treat it as a black-box authentication scheme you can build just about anything on top of it. There are very few good reasons not to use it.

If you must, the whole provider model has some pretty specific requirements, you can read about [implementing a membership provider](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f1kyba5e.aspx) or check out an example [ODBC membership provider](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6tc47t75.aspx).

Comment: I have read the msdn articles. My basic concern was if I am implementing one myself should I follow some regulations like implementing a particular Interface or abstract class or else my membership provider won't work

Comment: I'm really not sure how you read the articles and didn't get that you must implement certain abstract classes -- that is part and parcel with the entire concept of the Provider model.